# Heroku : This version of the API has been Sunset. is displayed when heroku pg:psql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

When I try to use `heroku pg:psql`, the following error is displayed.

`!    This version of the API has been Sunset.
 !    Please see https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1147 for more information.`

How can I access postgresql on Heroku?
`heroku pg:psql` command worked a few week ago.

I develop my Rails app on the Cloud 9.

Comment: I have the exact same issue! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my ruby on rails project since last Friday.

However, i was able to resolve this error message by update my heroku toolbelt on my mac os.

*Hint, if your heroku file was installed in project gem. you will need to delete that file.

Use command `which heroku` to identify where is the heroku file. if it is inside the .rvm folder that means your project is still using outdated heroku file. and simply remove it and then ran an new install heroku cli should fix this error.

Let me know if this works for you.